# COM Interoperability and Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I've encountered some issues with a .NET component that I am writing that is intended to be exposed to COM.

The class to be exposed inherits from a base class, both of which have ComVisible properties set to true. There's really nothing special about the base class - its contains 2 properties that I use to help abstract some database code.

I can register the assembly and type lib just fine. However, as soon as I attempt to instantiate the class, I get the following exception thrown from the callee:

Error in IDispatch.Invoke(): 0x80020101

I decided to debug it in CScript.exe and I was getting the same error. So I rewrote the class without the base class, and now I can create instances without issue.

Is there additional work I need to do in order to expose a .NET class that inherits from another .NET class in the same namespace?

Comment: Is the base class in the same DLL?

Comment: What happens if you make the parent class not COM visible.

Comment: One frustrating thing about this is that there doesn't seem to be any logging information in EventViewer; it just dies. Also, I tried it at first without specifyin ComVisible on the base class, which still causes the same error (it's actually showing up as "unknown error" in the VS2010 debugger, but I know the contents based on the exception thrown by the app calling the class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly use derived interfaces in a scripting language.  Scripting engines only supports a coclass that implements a single interface, the default interface.  Or to put it another way, scripting languages like vbscript or jscript are not object oriented languages that support multiple inheritance.  A workaround is to add a method to the default interface that returns a reference to the second interface.  Not commonly done, keeping it simple is boilerplate in scripting.

Comment: Thanks Hans... This makes sense, since not only did the call fail in CScript, but it also failed in the calling software because it uses VBScript to create the class instance.